# Easy way to Migrate from Twilio Flex UI 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

When I try to migrate my project from Flex 1.0 to 2.0, my UI breaks... some components are not working properly. So i've to change a lot of things in my code. Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [migration guide from Flex 1 to Flex 2 available here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/plugins/migration-guide).

Answer (score 0):

My company posted an article [here](https://visionpoint.systems/what-you-need-to-know-about-upgrading-to-twilio-flex-2-0/) that outlines what conditions make it so that upgrading to Flex 2.0 requires more than just a simple button click.

Generally, every customer will have a different path depending on what kind of custom plugins or chat functionality they are using.